# Online users with Spring Security

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and I would like to know which users are currently online. I first tried the approach using `SessionRegistryImpl` and `<session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="..." ... />`, but I guess this List is stored in memory and I would like to avoid it (it's going to be a huge website and a lot of users will be online at the same time, the List can become huge). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The second approach I tried is using a listener and the `HttpSessionListener` interface and a custom `AuthenticationManager` and storing the "is online flag" in the database. Basically, the flag is set to true in the `authenticate(...)` method of my authentication manager and set to false in the `sessionDestroyed(...)` method of my session listener.

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="my.package.security.AuthenticationManager" />

    <http disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/authorize" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login-failed" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
        <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </http>
</beans:beans>
```

my.package.SessionListener:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener
{
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)
    {

    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)
    {
        UserJpaDao userDao = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(httpSessionEvent.getSession().getServletContext()).getBean(UserJpaDao.class);

        Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(a != null)
        {
            User loggedInUser = userDao.findByAlias(a.getName());

            if(loggedInUser != null)
            {
                loggedInUser.setOnline(false);
                userDao.save(loggedInUser);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my.package.security.AuthenticationManager:

```
public class AuthenticationManager implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
{
    @Autowired
    UserJpaDao userDao;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        User loggedInUser = null;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = null;

        ...

        loggedInUser = userDao.findByAlias(authentication.getName());
        if(loggedInUser != null)
        {
            // Verify password etc.
            loggedInUser.setOnline(true);
            userDao.save(loggedInUser);
        }
        else
        {
            loggedInUser = null;
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Unknown username");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loggedInUser, authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

<s>`sessionCreated` and `sessionDestroyed` are fired correctly, but `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` is always null.</s>

**Update:** almost everything is working perfectly. The only problem is that when the session expires due to timeout, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns null in the `sessionDestroyed(...)` method. It works perfectly when the logout is manually triggered.

Can someone help me? Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to undertake the session registry method (only because I was not able to make the other method work). Here is my code (important parts).

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    ...

    <!-- Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="my.package.security.AuthenticationManager" />
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsDao" class="my.package.dao.UserDetailsDao" />

    <http disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/authorize" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login-failed" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
        <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" user-service-ref="userDetailsDao" />
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/invalid-session" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

my.package.security.AuthenticationManager:

```
public class AuthenticationManager implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
{
    @Autowired
    UserJpaDao userDao;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = null;

        if(authentication.getPrincipal() == null || authentication.getCredentials() == null)
        {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
        }

        User loggedInUser = userDao.findByAlias(authentication.getName());
        if(loggedInUser != null)
        {
            // TODO: check credentials
            userDetails = new UserDetails(loggedInUser);
        }
        else
        {
            loggedInUser = null;
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Unknown username");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, authentication.getCredentials(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

my.package.dao.UserDetailsDao (this is needed only for the remember-me functionality):

```
public class UserDetailsDao implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    UserJpaDao userDao;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user = userDao.findByAlias(username);
        if(user != null)
        {
            return new UserDetails(user);
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("The specified user cannot be found");
    }
}
```

my.package.UserDetails:

```
public class UserDetails implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
{
    private String alias;
    private String encryptedPassword;

    public UserDetails(User user)
    {
        this.alias = user.getAlias();
        this.encryptedPassword = user.getEncryptedPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.encryptedPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return this.alias;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()` will return a `List<Object>` "castable" to `List<UserDetails>`.

My code to get a list of online users, where the objects of type class `User` are persisted in the database through JPA:

```
List<User> onlineUsers = userDao.findByListOfUserDetails((List<UserDetails>)(List<?>)sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals());
```

Note: `sessionRegistry` is an Autowired implementation of the class `SessionRegistryImpl`.

Note: for the remember-me functionality, I'm using the persistent token approach. A `persistent_logins` is needed in the database (see [10.3 Persistent Token Approach](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html)).

Hope this may be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the `SecurityContextHolder` to get the Principal in your `SessionListener` since that is only valid in the context of a request.

All the info you need is in the Session itself

Example:

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    HttpSession session = se.getSession();
    SecurityContext context = (SecurityContext)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
    Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

    // Your code goes here

}
```

Comment: I can use SecurityContextHolder in case a user clicks the logout link, but in case of  session timeout works only this solution. Thank you! (I need it in order to protocol logouts.)