# How to check User Online Status with Spring Security in Grails?

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

We use Grails Spring Security in our application to perform user authentication. If a user loggs in to our application, the rememberMe cookie will be saved. This means, that the user will remain logend in between browser sessions.

How can I check which users are currently online? I read that you can retrieve this information from the Session using `SessionRegistryImpl` or `HttpSessionListener` but I have no idea how to implement that. I found this post but I am not sure how to transform it to Grails: [Online users with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211662/online-users-with-spring-security)

Any idea?

Comment: `grails install-templates` will give you your web.xml to edit. Its really exactly what they are doing.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I manage to get it working with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648100/grails-how-to-get-the-number-of-currently-signed-in-users-via-spring-security-c?rq=1 the problem is when a user loggs in and closes the browser. The session remains open. so what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I built a dating application that relies on online users. I created a Grails' Service that keeps track of online users. All you have to do is to create a service that keeps a concurrent hash map, the service is singleton so only one instance for the whole web application. When your user log-in for the first time, you set the user id, and a future time in the hash map. For example:

Key = UserID
Value = Now + 30min

So when the user logs in, you increment his log-in time with 30min and insert in the hash map. For every request the user sends, you update the value of the hash map by looking up his expiry time using his user id. So now if the user closes the browser, he is not going to update the expiry and his online status is going to be invalid. You can have a job that runs every 30min and remove those keys which have an expiry date of less than NOW. Or if you wanna count the online users, just loop through the map and count the entries which their expiry date is greater than NOW.

It's a hash map in memory, very easy to access and manipulate, and it's fast. That works great for me, and since I'm using a concurrent hash map, updates and reads are safe. Hope this helps you get what you want. Sorry that my answer is late but I just saw this question :)