# how to obtain a list of all currently logged-in users (including rememberme cookies) in grails with spring security

Tags: authentication, grails, cookies, spring-security

I'm building a grails app that has the spring-security-core 1.2.7.3 plugin as well as spring-security-ui 0.2 plugin, and would like to obtain a list of ALL the users that are currently logged in (ie have a currently active session). Users can login either through a login controller (daoAuthenticationProvider) or automatically through a rememberMe cookie.
I have implemented the code below, using ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy to create a sessionRegistry:

in /conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy

beans = {
userDetailsService(lablore.MyUserDetailsService)

    sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        maximumSessions = -1
    }

    concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
        expiredUrl = '/login/concurrentSession'
    }

}
```

In /plugins/spring-security-core/conf/DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy

```
useHttpSessionEventPublisher = true
```

In the controller:

```
controller{
    def sessionRegistry

    action(){
        def loggedInUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()
    }
}
```

It works well for 
-users that login through the login page
-users that logout through a 'logout' link
-users who's session expires
HOWEVER, it does NOT work for users that authenticate automatically with a rememberMe cookie. It doesn't see that they have a newly created session.
If I understand correctly, this is because the RememberMeAuthenticationFilter is 'further up' in the filter chain compared to the ConcurrentSessionFilter, which is the one running the sessionRegistry? Or, I messed something up with my configurations....

Any help on how to get this to work would be great !

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161974/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-all-active-sessions

Comment: another possibility would be to use a session listener. It shouldn't care how the user was authenticated.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573024/how-to-store-session-ids-and-associate-them-with-user/

Answer (score 2):

The  [ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html) is deprecated,

Use the [ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.html) instead

Alternatively,

You can implement the [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) interface which has the [sessionCreated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent))([HttpSessionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html) event) and [sessionDestroyed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent))([HttpSessionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html) event) methods, But you have to add the class you used

Implementations of this interface are notified of changes to the list of active sessions in a web application. To receive notification events, the implementation class must be configured in the deployment descriptor for the web application.

You can either add the implementation class to your deployment descriptor like so(i.e you web.xml file)

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.hazelcast.web.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

or by using the [WebXmlConfig](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) plugin in grails

Your implementation class could look like below, see [Online users with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211662/online-users-with-spring-security) also

```
class WebSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

     sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se){

          //Checked if user has logged in Here  and keep record 
              HttpSession webSession = se.getSession();

     }

     sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se){

          //Checked if user has logged in Here  and keep record     
            HttpSession webSession = se.getSession();
     }

}
```