# How to store session Id's and associate them with user

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have a `CustomSecurityEventListener` to obtain event after successful authentication and `CustomHttpSessionListener` to set max inactive session time.

```
class CustomSecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent>, LogoutHandler {

    def grailsApplication
    def sessionRegistry

    @Transactional
    void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) throws AuthenticationException {
        if(event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent){
            // user auditing actions

        }
}
```

I want to implement session manager with web interface where administrator will be able to revoke sessions belongs to the given user.

```
| userName1 | JSESSIONID1234 | action -> revoke |
| userName2 | JSESSIONID4321 | action -> revoke |
```

Do you have any adea how to associate sessionId with user by using Custom Listeners(using `sessionCreated()`, `sessionDestroyed()` methods) and store user-session pairs at in eg. "activeSession" collection.

I don't want to store sessionId as a property in the Spring Security User class.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following listener code to cleanup sessions when running functional tests.

Not exactly what your are looking for but `getAllPrincipals()` shows how you get the user from the session (I created that code using ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3').

```
import static org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY

class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    def sessions = [:].asSynchronized()

    void sessionCreated (HttpSessionEvent se) {
        sessions.put(se.session.id, se.session)
    }

    void sessionDestroyed (HttpSessionEvent se) {
        sessions.remove(se.session.id)
    }

    void invalidateSessions () {
        def httpSessions = sessions.collect {String sessionId, HttpSession session ->
            session
        }

        httpSessions.each { HttpSession session ->
            session.invalidate()
        }
    }

    def getAllPrincipals () {
        def principals = []
        sessions.each { String sessionId, HttpSession session ->
            SecurityContext securityContext = session[SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY]
            def authentication = securityContext?.authentication
            principals << authentication?.principal
        }
        principals = principals.findAll {it != null}
        principals
    }
}
```