# Grails 2.5.4: Get all logged in users with HttpSessionListener

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, httpsession

I'm trying to get all the current user sessions using the [app-info](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-app-info) plugin but it doesn't compile in `Grails 2.5.4`.  Is there another way to get this information?  I'm new to Grails.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788983/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-currently-logged-in-users-including-rememberme-cook) has some information including a reference to the app-info plugin but it's old and I wasn't able to get anything to compile.

**UPDATE**

I've added this custom class in `src\groovy\UserSessions`:

```
package usersessions

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener

//import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection
//import org.apache.shiro.subject.SimplePrincipalCollection;
//import org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DefaultSubjectContext

class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private static List activeUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) { }

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    String userName = getCurrentUserName(event)
    if (userName == null) {
        return
    }
    MyHttpSessionListener.userLoggedOut(userName)
}

public static void userLoggedIn(String userName) {
    if (!activeUsers.contains(userName)) {
        activeUsers.add(userName)
    }
}

public static void userLoggedOut(String userName) {
    activeUsers.remove(userName)
}

public static List getCurrentUserNames() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(activeUsers);
}
/* 
private String getCurrentUserName(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    PrincipalCollection currentUser = (PrincipalCollection) event.getSession().getAttribute(DefaultSubjectContext.PRINCIPALS_SESSION_KEY);
    if (currentUser == null) {
        return null
    }
    return (String) currentUser.getPrimaryPrincipal();
}
*/

}
```

Added this to `/scripts/_Events.groovy`

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

eventWebXmlEnd = {String tmpfile ->
    def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(webXmlFile)
    root.appendNode {
       'listener' {
       'listener-class' (
           'usersessions.MyHttpSessionListener'
       )
        }
    }

    webXmlFile.text = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace(
            "": "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee")
        mkp.yield(root)
    }
}
```

Added this to `resources.groovy`

```
myHttpSessionListener(usersessions.MyHttpSessionListener)
/*      shiroAuthenticator(ModularRealmAuthenticator) {
        authenticationStrategy = ref("shiroAuthenticationStrategy")
        authenticationListeners = [ ref("authListener") ]
    }
*/
```

Added this to my controller:

```
package usersessions

class NewController extends MyHttpSessionListener {
    def index() {
        myHttpSessionListener.userLoggedIn("user1")
        render "Users "+ getCurrentUserNames()
    }
 }
```

It compiles and the app runs but I don't see how to get sessions in the listener?  The controller gives an error when I load it:

> No such property: myHttpSessionListener for class: usersessions.NewController

**UPDATE 2**

I changed the controller to use this code to test creating a sessions and it works:

```
def index() {        
    String randomString = org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(3, true, true)
    userLoggedIn(randomString)  
    render "Users "+ getCurrentUserNames()
}
```

Comment: https://classpattern.com/spring-security-sessionregistry-on-grails. The current user Sessions is collected by the https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-app-info/blob/master/src/java/com/burtbeckwith/grails/plugins/appinfo/ContextListener.java which is called here - https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-app-info/blob/2efc83fa5d268ce6cad9c3c7885dc23ae2bead65/grails-app/services/grails/plugins/appinfo/ScopesInfoService.groovy#L100-L106 but you need to declare a http listener bean to start up with app typically done in resources.groovy

Comment: @Vahid The grails app I'm using doesn't use spring security for authentication, it uses a custom security component.  Will this still work?  When I install spring-security it directs to the login controllers installed by spring-security.

Comment: Sorry ignore the first link but the rest are relevant, if you want to see who is connected via your sessions then you need a session listener that you also need to declare here is another example within a grails 2 app : https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener/blob/master/src/groovy/mydemo/MyHttpSessionListener.groovy  you would declare it typically like this but for that class https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener/blob/master/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy#L9   access the list via from a controller: `mydemo.MyHttpSessionListener.activeUsers`

Comment: @Vahid I created `MyHttpSessionListener` and registered it in `resources.groovy`.  When I try to add the implementation in a controller there is an error on the class declaration line : `class NewController extends MyHttpSessionListener {`, error is: `Unable to resolve class MyHttpSessionListener`.  The controller and `MyHttpSessionListener` are in the same package.

Comment: Eh why do you need to extend the httpsessionListener, the listener is a class that by being registered in the resources.groovy. Sorry I also forgot check the home page of the project: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener scripts/_Events.groovy: take a look at the event I added in there to get it to trigger the listener. That is all you need to do - in the Controller you simply need to reference the static object in the httpListener to extract / list  the stored sessions so by simply doing def index() { render  text: "${mydemo.MyHttpSessionListener.activeUsers}"  }

Comment: I see I had extended it in my example, anyhow I don't think you need to extend that activeUsers is a static object in that Listener meaning anytime you refer to it - like I shown above it should work from anywhere, even in a gsp. I would possibly convert it from private declaration to public to make it accessible from outside of the context

Comment: @Vahid I extended because I was following your example and I'm new to grails and groovy.  That's good that I don't need to extend it. I don't see where the trigger in _Events.groovy?  Can you show me that? Also, I had to comment out these imports because it can't find them.  How do I get those in my project?  `import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection 
import org.apache.shiro.subject.SimplePrincipalCollection; import org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DefaultSubjectContext`

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener/blob/master/scripts/_Events.groovy is here you need to have the same thing in your app. Grails internally runs this as it starts up - If you commment out https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener/blob/master/src/groovy/mydemo/MyHttpSessionListener.groovy#L38-L44 these lines you won't need those imports. That part of it relates to the shiro part of that example application uploaded. The app was a custom shiro test for others....

Comment: @Vahid I removed extends and made activeUsers public.  Now I can access it be referencing the class in my controllers.  I am new to grails, how do I get those imports into my grails app?  Do I need to download them from somewhere?  I am not using shiro framework in my app but I need this PrincipalCollection to make the override function getCurrentUserName work.  `import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection import org.apache.shiro.subject.SimplePrincipalCollection; import org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DefaultSubjectContext`

Comment: Really hard to comment, you say you are using a custom authentication mechanism but there isn't much details of what you are doing/using. If you are new to grails I suggest you stick with provided plugins on grails 2 apps. On grails 2 - there were 2 choices shiro plugin or grails spring security.  https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L71 shiro plugin is available via this line. There is also another shiro as well as kchat projects on my repo - they use shiro

Comment: I need to uncomment this function https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-shiro-listener/blob/master/src/groovy/mydemo/MyHttpSessionListener.groovy#L38-L44 for it to work.  I'd like to just use `import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection`. Could I write my own `PrincipalCollection` for this line?  `PrincipalCollection currentUser = (PrincipalCollection) event.getSession().getAttribute(DefaultSubjectContext.PRINCIPALS_SESSION_KEY);` or does it need to be from the `shiro` import?

Comment: Really unsure what you are trying to do `PrincipalCollection` is part of Shiro plugin, which is why the import comes from that path. Not entirely too sure what your authentication mechanism is, your initial question related to httpsession and listing those - which the comments answer. If you are trying to invent the wheel as in make your own auth system I highly recommend using one out of the box either Shiro/spring security - They were 2 plugins supported auth on grails 2 platform. Perhaps raise a new question that outlines exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Perhaps I have missed something, did you manage to list httpsessions ?

Comment: @Vahid.  I'm not trying to create an authentication system.  Just trying to store all current users.  I figured it out. Instead of the line in your example `//PrincipalCollection currentUser = (PrincipalCollection) event.getSession().getAttribute(DefaultSubjectContext.PRINCIPALS_SESSION_KEY);` I used `String currentUser = (String)event.getSession().userName;`